# Prevent form submit if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, checkbox

I'm using some Ajax / Javascript to prevent the form submit if an input field is empty.

```
$(function() {

    var form = $('#contact-form-edc');

    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        var formData = $(form).serialize();

  if (document.getElementById("nachricht-field").value.length < 10) {
    document.getElementById('error-nachricht').style.display = "";
  } else {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })

        .done(function(response) {
         document.getElementById('success').style.display = "";
          document.getElementById('error').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('error-nachricht').style.display = "none";

            $('input').val('');
   $('textarea').val('');
   $('.button').val('Abschicken');
   $('input[name=datenschutz]').attr('checked', false);
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
           document.getElementById('error').style.display = "";
            document.getElementById('success').style.display ="none";
        });

  }

    });

});
```

The script works fine but do not note the checkbox of the form. The checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="datenschutz" value="Datenschutz" required="required" >
```

is required as well but the user can submit the form without checking the checkbox. Is there a small script which I can implement in the current Ajax-Script?

Comment: varChecked = $('input[name="datenschutz"]:checked').length;
if(Checked>0){
//do stuff here

}else{
//do stuff here
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this way:

```
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find('input[name="datenschutz"]')[0].checked === false)
      return false;
    // rest of form
```

If you want to add a message, you can go ahead this way:

```
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find('input[name="datenschutz"]')[0].checked === false) {
      alert("Please accept the terms and conditions!");
      return false;
    }
    // rest of form
```

Comment: just to help to improve a tiny the code: `$(form).find("input[name='datenschutz']"])` so it will find the checkbox of that form

Comment: I 'corrected' one instance of spelling, my apologies if you disagree with my change. Obviously feel free to roll back if you wish.

Comment: @Cheshire Check this out. I have included it in my answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas That's perfectly right *informal* way of want to. `:P` If you want me to be professional, okay, no problems. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar nice =)

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` should be inside `if statement` otherwise if checkbox is checked the form doesn't submit as normal

Comment: @aletede91 It **should not** submit traditionally. It's an AJAX form. `:)` From the question: *I'm using some Ajax / Javascript to prevent the form submit if...*

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest enabling the submit button when the check-box is checked:

```
// binding an anonymous function to handle the change event:
$('input[name=datenschutz]').on('change', function () {
    var input = this;

    // navigating to the form 'this.form',
    // finding the submit button (obviously correct the
    // selector),
    // setting the disabled property of the submit button to
    // to be false when the check-box is checked, and true
    // when the check-box is unchecked:
    $(input.form).find('submitButtonSelector').prop('disabled', !input.checked});
});
```